# How do I reverse a number in Java using String?

Tags: java, string

I have used the below logic, but getting an exception "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException". Help will be appreciated. Thank you!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Demo{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number:- ");
        String number = sc.next();                      

        for (int i = number.length(); i >= 0; i--) {    
            System.out.println(number.charAt(i));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `int i = number.length() - 1`

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed, i.e. the index range is `[0, length - 1]`.

Comment: `String number = new StringBuilder(sc.next()).reverse().toString();`

Answer (score 1):

You only need to iterate across the string halfway, swapping the characters as the indices go towards the middle.  This works for even or odd length strings.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number:- ");
char[] chars = sc.next().toCharArray();
int len = chars.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
     char c1 = chars[i];
     char c2 = chars[len-i-1];
     chars[i] = c2;
     chars[len-i-1] = c1;
}
String s = new String(chars);
System.out.println(s);
```

Or just use the [`reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) method included in the [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Demo{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number:- ");
        String number = sc.next();                      

        for (int i = number.length() -1 ; i >= 0; i--) {    // correct answer: number.lenght() -1 as array start with 0.
            System.out.print(number.charAt(i)); //using print instead of println so that it display in same line
        }

    }

}
```